# New Istanbul Airport and 1 hour for change from domestic flight to international flight

Tags: transit, short-connections, ist

So I will have **exactly one hour** between flights on **IST** airport.
Different reservations, no guarantee for missed flight.

Turkish Airlines domestic inbound 16:30 <->
LOT Polish Airlines international outbound 17:30

The question is **will I make it?**

Do anybody know if it is easy and relatively quick to change after arrival or is there a need to leave and re-enter the whole facility?
What about passport checks?
From what I checked there are no seperate terminals between domestic and international flights so I think that I will arrive in common area so in theory it should be easy to change the gate (+go through passport control)

Any tips and experiences shared here will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Do you have any checked bags? If so, I would say this is completely impossible. Also, when are you doing the trip? Are you sure both flights are still operating? LOT has cancelled all flights for at least 2 weeks.

Comment: no checked luggage, travelling light, september but with 1yr old child...

Comment: With a 1 year old, I would definitely not take any risks. Getting stuck in an airport for hours because you missed your flight is not fun. Getting stuck in an airport for hours with a baby... very bad idea. Also remember that we have no idea what the situation will be in September, for all we know there could still be significant disruption. If you want to book, your first choice should definitely be connecting flights on a single booking. Otherwise, you should have **at least** 4 hours between flights, and be sure to have good travel insurance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not a chance! IIRC domestic arrivals exit landside and re-enter airside through passport and security control, which won't be that quick.

You should **not** book this on separate reservations. In fact the minimum connection time domestic-international at IST is 90 minutes.

Comment: Thanks, I actually waited with the booking until get answered here so no harm. Now I now I need to find a way to arrange thing differently, cheers

Comment: @Heps Anything that is in a single booking is OK, as you're then insured (but you seem to know that already)